# Magento 2: Graphql Custom collection data returns null

Tags: magento2, collection, graphql

> I'm creating Graphql for my custom module, but after
> setting an endpoint and writing a query for it, does not return
> any data.

**Below are the files I have created for Graphql,**

> **MyVendor/RMAModule/etc/schema.graphqls**

```
type Query {
    RmaResolver (
        emailId: String @doc(description: "Email Address")
    ): RmaResolver @resolver(class:"MyVendor\\RMAModule\\Model\\Resolver\\RmaResolver") @doc(description:"Custom Module Datapassing")
}

type RmaResolver {
    rmaData: [RmaRecord] @doc(description: "RMA records")
}

type RmaRecord {
    entity_id : Int @doc(description: "Entity Id")
    order_id : Int @doc(description: "Order Id")
    customer_id : Int @doc(description: "Customer Id")
    customer_name : String @doc(description: "Customer Name")
    customer_email : String @doc(description: "Customer Email")
    delivery_status : String @doc(description: "Delivery Status")
    additional_info : String @doc(description: "Additional Info")
    rma_status : String @doc(description: "RMA Status")
    created_on : String @doc(description: "Created on")
}
```

> **MyVendor/RMAModule/Model/Resolver/RmaResolver.php**

```
    <?php
namespace MyVendor\RMAModule\Model\Resolver;
 
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ValueFactory;
use MyVendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaFactory;

class RmaResolver implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ValueFactory
     */
    private $valueFactory; 

    /**
     * @var RmaFactory
     */
    protected $rmaFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;
 
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

     /**
     * @param ValueFactory $valueFactory     
     * @param RmaFactory $rmaFactory
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array
     */
    public function __construct(
        ValueFactory $valueFactory,
        RmaFactory $rmaFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->valueFactory = $valueFactory;
        $this->rmaFactory = $rmaFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

     /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null)
    {
        try{
            $emailId = $this->getEmailId($args);
            $rmaData = $this->getRmaData($emailId);

            $result = function () use ($rmaData) {
                return !empty($rmaData) ? $rmaData : [];
            };            
            return $this->valueFactory->create($result);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

     /**
     * @param array $args
     * @return int
     * @throws GraphQlInputException
     */
    public function getEmailId(array $args): int
    {
        if (!isset($args['emailId'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('EmailId should be specified'));
        }
 
        return (int)$args['emailId'];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws GraphQlNoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getRmaData(string $emailId): array
    {
        $emailNotExist = $this->emailExistOrNot($emailId);

        if($emailNotExist){
            // Guest User
            $rmaCollection = $this->rmaFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter("customer_email", $emailId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', null);
        }else{
            // Customer
            $customerData = $this->customerRepository->get($emailId);
            $customerId = (int)$customerData->getId();
            $rmaCollection = $this->rmaFactory->create()->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter("customer_id", $customerId);
        }

        $output['rmaData'] = [];
        foreach ($rmaCollection as $rmaItem) {
            // $output['rmaData'][] = [
            //     'entity_id' => $rmaItem['entity_id'],
            //     'order_id' => $rmaItem['order_id'],
            //     'customer_id' => $rmaItem['customer_id'],
            //     'customer_name' => $rmaItem['customer_name'],
            //     'customer_email' => $rmaItem['customer_email'],
            //     'delivery_status' => $rmaItem['delivery_status'],
            //     'additional_info' => $rmaItem['additional_info'],
            //     'rma_status' => $rmaItem['rma_status'],
            //     'created_on' => $rmaItem['created_on']
            // ];
            $rmaId = $rmaItem->getId();
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['entity_id'] = $rmaItem['entity_id'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['order_id'] = $rmaItem['order_id'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['customer_id'] = $rmaItem['customer_id'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['customer_name'] = $rmaItem['customer_name'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['customer_email'] = $rmaItem['customer_email'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['delivery_status'] = $rmaItem['delivery_status'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['additional_info'] = $rmaItem['additional_info'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['rma_status'] = $rmaItem['rma_status'];
            $output['rmaData'][$rmaId]['created_on'] = $rmaItem['created_on'];
        }
        return $output;
       
    }

    /**
     * Returns Email Id exist or not
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function emailExistOrNot($emailId): bool
    {
        $websiteId = (int)$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
        $isEmailNotExists = $this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($emailId, $websiteId);
        return $isEmailNotExists;
    }
}
```

**I have set an endpoint as `http://127.0.0.1/magento243/graphql` and the query is,**

```
{
  RmaResolver(emailId: "abc@example.com") {
    rmaData{
      entity_id
      order_id
      customer_id
      customer_name
      customer_email
      delivery_status
      additional_info
      rma_status
      created_on
    }
  }
}
```

**But the result is blank array,**

```
{
  "data": {
    "RmaResolver": {
      "rmaData": []
    }
  }
}
```

**I have also created an API for getting data and with the API I'm getting records. FYI defined email-id is a customer and has rma records.**

**Please let me know if anyone has a solution.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update below files and run magetno 2 upgrade and cache clean command**

MyVendor/RMAModule/etc/schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
    RmaResolver (
        emailId: String @doc(description: "Email Address")
    ): [RmaRecord] @resolver(class:"MyVendor\\RMAModule\\Model\\Resolver\\RmaResolver") @doc(description:"Custom Module Datapassing")
}

type RmaRecord {
    entity_id : Int @doc(description: "Entity Id")
    order_id : Int @doc(description: "Order Id")
    customer_id : Int @doc(description: "Customer Id")
    customer_name : String @doc(description: "Customer Name")
    customer_email : String @doc(description: "Customer Email")
    delivery_status : String @doc(description: "Delivery Status")
    additional_info : String @doc(description: "Additional Info")
    rma_status : String @doc(description: "RMA Status")
    created_on : String @doc(description: "Created on")
}
```

MyVendor/RMAModule/Model/Resolver/RmaResolver.php

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\RMAModule\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ValueFactory;
use MyVendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaFactory;

class RmaResolver implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ValueFactory
     */
    private $valueFactory;

    /**
     * @var RmaFactory
     */
    protected $rmaFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

     /**
     * @param ValueFactory $valueFactory
     * @param RmaFactory $rmaFactory
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array
     */
    public function __construct(
        ValueFactory $valueFactory,
        RmaFactory $rmaFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->valueFactory = $valueFactory;
        $this->rmaFactory = $rmaFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

     /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null)
    {
        try{
            return $this->getRmaData($args);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        return [];
    }

     /**
     * @param array $args
     * @return int
     * @throws GraphQlInputException
     */
    public function getEmailId(array $args): int
    {
        if (!isset($args['emailId'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('EmailId should be specified'));
        }
        return (int)$args['emailId'];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws GraphQlNoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getRmaData(string $emailId): array
    {
        $emailNotExist = $this->emailExistOrNot($emailId);

        if($emailNotExist){
            // Guest User
            $rmaCollection = $this->rmaFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter("customer_email", $emailId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', null);
        }else{
            // Customer
            $customerData = $this->customerRepository->get($emailId);
            $customerId = (int)$customerData->getId();
            $rmaCollection = $this->rmaFactory->create()->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter("customer_id", $customerId);
        }

        $output = [];
        foreach ($rmaCollection as $rmaItem) {
            // $output['rmaData'][] = [
            //     'entity_id' => $rmaItem['entity_id'],
            //     'order_id' => $rmaItem['order_id'],
            //     'customer_id' => $rmaItem['customer_id'],
            //     'customer_name' => $rmaItem['customer_name'],
            //     'customer_email' => $rmaItem['customer_email'],
            //     'delivery_status' => $rmaItem['delivery_status'],
            //     'additional_info' => $rmaItem['additional_info'],
            //     'rma_status' => $rmaItem['rma_status'],
            //     'created_on' => $rmaItem['created_on']
            // ];
            $rmaId = $rmaItem->getId();
            $output[$rmaId]['entity_id'] = $rmaItem['entity_id'];
            $output[$rmaId]['order_id'] = $rmaItem['order_id'];
            $output[$rmaId]['customer_id'] = $rmaItem['customer_id'];
            $output[$rmaId]['customer_name'] = $rmaItem['customer_name'];
            $output[$rmaId]['customer_email'] = $rmaItem['customer_email'];
            $output[$rmaId]['delivery_status'] = $rmaItem['delivery_status'];
            $output[$rmaId]['additional_info'] = $rmaItem['additional_info'];
            $output[$rmaId]['rma_status'] = $rmaItem['rma_status'];
            $output[$rmaId]['created_on'] = $rmaItem['created_on'];
        }
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Returns Email Id exist or not
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function emailExistOrNot($emailId): bool
    {
        $websiteId = (int)$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
        $isEmailNotExists = $this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($emailId, $websiteId);
        return $isEmailNotExists;
    }
}
```

**Query is:**

```
query RmaResolver {
    RmaResolver(emailId: "abc@example.com"){
        entity_id
        order_id
        customer_id
        customer_name
        customer_email
        delivery_status
        additional_info
        rma_status
        created_on
    }
}
```

**[Update]**
**Check Below For Your Reference, It might help you.**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/schema.graphqls**

```
type Query {
    getbytype (
        type: Int @doc(description: "get Banner by type")
    ): [getbyytype] @resolver(class: "VendoreName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\BannerType") @doc(description: "The query returns the banner belong to type id")
}

type getbyytype @doc(description: "all Attributes to show in Product Details Page") {
    banner_id : Int  @doc(description: "Banner Id")
    title : String  @doc(description: "Title")
    status : Int  @doc(description: "Status")
    image : String  @doc(description: "If image then show")
    banner_title : String  @doc(description: "Banner title")
    color_picker : String  @doc(description: "Colore Picker title")
    color_picker_bg: String  @doc(description: "Background Colore Picker title")
    banner_content : String  @doc(description: "Banner Content")
    banner_type : Int  @doc(description: "Banner Type")
    button_show : Int  @doc(description: "Button Show status")
    button_txt : String  @doc(description: "Button text")
    button_color : String  @doc(description: "Button colore")
    display_position : Int  @doc(description: "Display Position ")
    position : Int  @doc(description: "Position")
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver/BannerType.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class BannerType implements ResolverInterface
{
    private $bannertypeDataProvider;

    /**
     * @param DataProvider\BannerType $bannertypeDataProvider
     */
    public function __construct(
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\DataProvider\BannerType $bannertypeDataProvider
    ) {
        $this->bannertypeDataProvider = $bannertypeDataProvider;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        //by Type
        $type = $this->getType($args);
        $bannerData = $this->bannertypeDataProvider->getByType($type);
        return $bannerData;
    }

    private function getType(array $args)
    {
        if (!isset($args['type'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('"Type should be specified'));
        }
        return $args['type'];
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/BannerType.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\DataProvider;

class BannerType extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_bannerTypeData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\BannerFactory $bannerTypeData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_bannerTypeData = $bannerTypeData;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @params int $id
     * this function return all the word of the day by id
     **/
    public function getByType($type)
    {
        $atr_data = $this->_bannerTypeData->create()->getCollection();
        $atr_data->addFieldToFilter('display_position', $type);
        $attributes_data = [];
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($atr_data as $attribute) {
            $attributes_data[$x]['banner_id'] = $attribute->getId();
            $attributes_data[$x]['title'] = $attribute->getTitle();
            $attributes_data[$x]['status'] = $attribute->getStatus();
            $attributes_data[$x]['image'] = $attribute->getImage();
            $attributes_data[$x]['banner_title'] = $attribute->getBannerTitle();
            $attributes_data[$x]['color_picker'] = $attribute->getColorPicker();
            $attributes_data[$x]['color_picker_bg'] = $attribute->getColorPickerBg();
            $attributes_data[$x]['banner_content'] = $attribute->getBannerContent();
            $attributes_data[$x]['button_show'] = $attribute->getButtonShow();
            $attributes_data[$x]['button_txt'] = $attribute->getButtonTxt();
            $attributes_data[$x]['button_color'] = $attribute->getButtonColor();
            $attributes_data[$x]['banner_type'] = $attribute->getBannerType();
            $attributes_data[$x]['display_position'] = $attribute->getDisplayPosition();
            $attributes_data[$x]['position'] = $attribute->getPosition();
            $x++;
        }
        return $attributes_data;
    }
}
```

**Query is:**

```
query getbytype {
  getbytype(type: 2) {
    banner_id
    title
    status
    image
    banner_title
    color_picker
    color_picker_bg
    banner_content
    banner_type
    button_show
    button_txt
    button_color
    display_position
    position
  }
}
```

***Note: Must be run upgrade and cache clean command.***

> Please try with static data and you can use echo and print_r() and
> check into the network tab to inspect (F12) to see data and log
>
> MyVendor/RMAModule/Model/Resolver/RmaResolver.php

**Before changes**

```
/**
 * @param array $args
 * @return int
 * @throws GraphQlInputException
 */
public function getEmailId(array $args): int
{
    if (!isset($args['emailId'])) {
        throw new GraphQlInputException(__('EmailId should be specified'));
    }
    return (int)$args['emailId'];
}
```

**After Changes which is working**

```
/**
     * @param array $args
     * @return string
     * @throws GraphQlInputException
     */
    public function getEmailId(array $args): string
    {
        if (!isset($args['emailId'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('EmailId should be specified'));
        }
 
        return (string)$args['emailId'];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried that as well I have updated the `RmaResolver.php` file in question.

Comment: I have updated the `resolve()` and `getRmaData()` but still it shows blank

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: okay i will try this

Comment: still data is blank.

Comment: @MohitRane I added my files which help you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will check it out.

Comment: I made file changes as you suggested, but still, the data is blank. Can I log the data in a log file to check if the data is there? i tried with the PSR logger but it didn't log. Although I can get the data with the same code in API

Comment: please try with static data and you can use echo and print_r()  and check into the network tab to inspect (F12) to see data and log. Above my files are working. https://dolphinwebsolution.com/how-to-get-custom-module-data-in-to-graphql-magento-2

Comment: That was on point checking with the static data, turned out `$emailId = $this->getEmailId($args);` this $emailId isn't returning anything because I was returning the int from `getEmailId()`

Comment: You can update the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You can also edit my answer and accept. I remove that line.

Comment: Updated an answer please check

Comment: Yes, thanks now you can accept it.

Comment: Yup already accepted, Thank you so much for your guidance and reference.